# Step Into Property/Function (F11) doesn't work as expected

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

In Visual Studio 2010, the Step Into Property/Function (<kbd>F11</kbd>) doesn't work as expected.

It doesn't step into property setters or getters.

I converted the solution from `Visual Studio 2005` to `2010`, the function i wanted to step into is a property in a separate class library.

How can I make it work as I expect?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

In VS 2010 it is the default setting that you step over properties and operators(like <kbd>F10</kbd>) even if you want to step into(<kbd>F11</kbd>). So here is the solution:

- Go to Tools > Options menu in Visual Studio.
- Go to Debugging > General menu item in left pane.
- In right view you will see an option Step over properties and operators (Managed only). Uncheck this option and then you are all set.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing what you found. I actually found documentation on this as the first hit when I googled "visual studio 2010 step into properties" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667388.aspx.

What I'm trying to figure out is when you uncheck the "Step over properties..." option, it seems to have the reverse problem: It always steps into properties, even if you use the Step Over command. Isn't there a way to control whether you step over or into a property on a line by line basis (using keyboard shortcuts) like in Visual Studio 2005?

Comment: @xr280xr: It works for me to hit F10 instead of F11(Step into). If the property has no explicit getter and setter then it always steps over even with F10. If it has a getter/setter F10 skips the property whereas F11 will enter the property.

Comment: not for me. If Step over properties and operators is unchecked, F10 always steps into property getters and setters. That's what I was referring to above. Thanks for letting me know yours works correctly. This wouldn't be the first time I've had VS 2010 completely lose its mind and stop working correctly.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. although now it steps into *everything*. It's unfortunate that the default behavior isn't a little more intelligent. That is, it could step over the simplest get or set which is just a single line of code equivalent to what VS itself would generate for a property. But some setters do all kinds of things; seems odd to not step into those.

Comment: @JCoombs If you only have a small number of properties that you're interested in stepping into, you can always leave the option checked but breakpoint the property accessors. Of course, in VS2010+ the "simplest" getters and setters are the ones without a body at all, and those *are* skipped over.

Comment: @JCoombs while debugging you can right click the line and toggle the [Step over properties and operators](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21360151/641833) setting.

Comment: @Trisped Thanks; that's good to know as a more convenient way of accessing that setting. But it still doesn't give me a nice middle ground. When I'm debugging someone else's code (or my own older stuff), I don't necessarily remember which getters/setters have real code in them, so I end up stepping into tons of empty ones, or else skipping them all and missing part of the execution logic while debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me on Visual Studio **2015**: I closed VS and deleted folder: ***.vs*** (hidden folder, some times together with solution file) and opened again Visual Studio.