# .NET Form Ignores button.Enabled flag

Tags: .net, forms, button, boolean

I am trying to set a button to the Enabled state when certain conditions are met, but it doesn't seem to pay attention to when I set it to true. When I debug through the code, and put a watch on the Enabled variable, it changes to true, but when I mouseover the variable after it is set to true, it still says it is false. The button remains disabled when it needs to be enabled. Has anyone else ever run into this?

Here is the code I am having issues with:

```
if (!thisCondition){
     this.btnOK.Enabled = true;
}
```

There's really not much more to it... it seems silly I know.

Comment: have you got your code or portion there of?

Comment: Is the button inside of any container control that is `Enabled=False`?

Comment: If you want to see the code then I'll post it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, there was a function that the debugger was stepping over that I failed to notice that was setting the value back arbitrarily. Gotta love unreadable code!

Comment: Was it a property where Visual Studio stepped over? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873225/visual-studio-2010-step-into-property-functionf11-doesnt-work-as-expected/4873299#4873299

Comment: No, it was a function that was very convoluted and hard to read, and in my frustration I blew right past it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a control that you enable, but it is within a disabled parent control, it will remain disabled.

Comment: It's definitely not within a disabled parent control, the Cancel button works fine and they are inside the same container.

Comment: Then try hooking the EnabledChanged event of the button to see when it is getting set back to False.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any mouseevent?
Are you in a for or while condition? 
The else condition, is it present?

Comment: It is inside a loop, but if I step through the loop line by line, the same thing happens. It hits the "this.OKBtn.Enabled = true;" code, it just... doesn't switch... I also put in an "Application.DoEvents()" call at the end of the method to force it to draw, still nothing.