# Why vb code is not executed step by step by using F11?

Tags: vb.net

I am new to vb. When I started to work on this new project in vb.net 2010, I put many breakpoints to try to understand the execution order of the project, only to find it in vain.

Step into command <kbd>F11</kbd> should work correctly according to [Step Into Property/Function (F11) doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873225/visual-studio-2010-step-into-property-functionf11-doesnt-work-as-expected). But I when I pressed <kbd>F11</kbd>, I found the code is jumping from one place to another based on breakpoints, not line by line or step by step.

To give an example, please see the code below

```
    Me.tcData.Alignment = TabStrip.TabControl.TabAlignment.Bottom   'line 1-breakpoint
    Me.tcData.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill            'line 2
    ...
    Me.tcData.TabsDirection = TabStrip.TabControl.FlowDirection.LeftToRight  'line 3

Public Property Alignment() As TabAlignment           'The property 1 called by line 1
    Get
        Return m_Alignment
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As TabAlignment)
        m_Alignment = value
        AdjustHeight()
        PositionButtons()
        For Each t As TabPage In TabPages
            t.Alignment = value
        Next
    End Set
End Property


Public Property TabsDirection() As FlowDirection 'The property 3 -breakpoint
    Get
        Return m_TabsDirection
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As FlowDirection)
        m_TabsDirection = value
        SelectItem(Nothing)
    End Set
End Property
```

When I press <kbd>F11</kbd> at line 1, it goes to the property 1. After it returns, when I press <kbd>F11</kbd>,it goes to property 3 directly, without accessing the code in line 2 and line 3.

I do not understand why the code is NOT executed step by step by using <kbd>F11</kbd>. If I put breakpoingts in line 2, then line 2 is executed.

So it seems to me that the showed execution order is based on breakpoints! So if I put breakpoints at different places, the showed execution order would be different! Thus, it is impossible for me to really understand the execution order.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you tell it to `Step Into`, it follows the exact code path. So in order to calculate `TabStrip.TabControl.TabAlignment.Bottom` in line one, it first has to reference `TabStrip`, then look up the `TabControl` property, then look up the `TabAlignment` property, then-- Here's where it jumps to the property 1 label, right? That's because it has to execute the `Get` section for the `TabAlignment` property in your code. Once it executes that, it knows what the reference is, and so it returns that back to the previous level of execution, at which point it can look up the `Bottom` property. Now, it can assign the value to the `Me.tcData.Alignment` property.

The same goes for line 3: In order to know where it is assigning `TabStrip.TabControl.FlowDirection.LeftToRight` to, it has to evaluate the `Me.tcData.TabsDirection` property, which involves executing your code in the `Get` section of your `TabsDirection` property.

So, in short, you are seeing the exact execution path that the code is following, including all the "sub-evaluations" that have to be performed to calculate both the "source" and "destination" properties. Depending on the debugger configuration, it might not show this for system code, but if you set the debugger to be as verbose as possible, it will jump to the `Get` definition for every property you reference, including system code. There are 5 property lookups for `System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill`, just to assign it to a local variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I know line 1 will jump to property 1. But after it returns, should not it go to line 2 and then line 3. Then line 3 will refer to the property 3. But my situation is that after returning to line 1, I see the execution in property 3 directly, without execution of line 2 and line 3.

Comment: Check the call stack when it jumps to property three to see how it got there. Any revealing information in there?

Comment: Good point. I checked call stack and property 3 is indeed called by line 3. Just line 3 is not showed to be executed when I use F11..Strange, right? I guess I miss some settings in tools->options, I should try to figure out