# F11 Key (Debug Mode) not working in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

In my Visual Studio 2010, <kbd>F11</kbd> Key s not working.

I tried [Step Into Property/Function (F11) doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873225/visual-studio-2010-step-into-property-functionf11-doesnt-work-as-expected) But it didn't help me.

The same works it when I go to Debug menu and click on Step Into.

Can you help me out? It has become a very big problem for me!

Comment: "ended in failure" isn't a very helpful description of what happened. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: It's not a lot of information you give here but it's possible that you are using resharper or another add-on that overrides the F11 key. Does it work when clicking on the "step over icon" in the tool bar with the mouse?

Comment: I'm sorry if you didn't get it.

Comment: Yes it works if I go to Debug menu and click on Step Over

Comment: I don't understand why you're reluctant to give us more information. The more detail you give us, the more likely it is that we can help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet I do not understand what information i have to give you? Please name it.

Comment: @Krishna: Normally F11 is step into, not step over. Which are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm sorry @JonSkeet I've mistaken both the Step into and Step Over are working if I click on them manually by going into the debug menu and click on them

Comment: It working by mouse click suggests that the hot key is in fact overridden

Comment: @EasierSaidThanDone Can you suggest me what to do?

Comment: Can any one know how to undo override F11 Key??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to go to `Tools>Options` and there to `Environment>Keyboard`. Type into the text field with the title "Show commands containing:" the term "StepInto". This filters the list below. Select "Debug.StepInto". Check if F11 is registered for "Global". If not do so.

If you have resharper installed go to the resharper options, select `Visual Studio Integration` and deselect the resharper shortcuts. Id you have anything else overriding the shortcuts try their option/keyboard/shortcut menues.

Play around with those options a little if it doesn't work immediately before you get back here.

Hope that helps.

Comment: There is already F11 Key Registered as Global. I removed it and tried to add but it is not recognizing f11 when Key is pressed. It is recognizing other keys. I changed my keyboard and tried but the same problem persists.

Answer (score 8):

Check if you have function lock key -- 'F Lock' key on keyboard. If so then try pressing it once and then press <kbd>F11</kbd> for debuging.

Alternatively you can verify the working of <kbd>F11</kbd> outside Visual Studio using it on IE or other windows and keying <kbd>F11</kbd>, this should maximize the window.

Comment: F Lock it is. You are the star.

Answer (score 0):

Check if <kbd>F11</kbd> key is working, did happen to me today that the <kbd>F11</kbd> is faulty in key board

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Visual Studio in Microsoft Remote Desktop on macOS, F11 might be assigned to "Show Desktop".

To disable: Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard shortcuts… > Mission Control > Show Desktop.

(It could also be assigned to another shortcut)