# User control property fails on set

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control on a webform. I have public properties backed by viewstate on the user control. In the code-behind of the webform I attempt to set the public properties. When I debug through the code behind at the point of the set the debugger never takes me to the setter. Likewise the value of the textbox for the public property never gets set. Why?

```
//aspx page with reference to user control on a telerik tab/page view
<telerik:RadPageView ID="radpvCommunication" runat="server">
    <uc:Communication ID="Communication1" runat="server" />
</telerik:RadPageView>

//Webform method to set user control public property
private void SetCommunicationControlText()
{
    Communication1.SubjectTextBoxText = "This is a test set from organization";
}

//user control code
public partial class CommunicationUserControl : UserControl
{
    public string SubjectTextBoxText
    {
        get { return ViewState["SubjectTextBoxText"].ToString(); }
        set { ViewState["SubjectTextBoxText"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you put a breakpoint on `SetCommunicationControlText` and step into that assignment?  To step into properties, see this stackoverflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4873299/507793

Comment: It never steps in. It steps over the next line. Like I hit the F10, not F11.

Comment: Where are you calling `SetCommunicationControlText` method from?

Comment: Alright, so it appears I had to two issues. I'm down to one. I can step into that property now. However, the value 'this is a test set...' is not in the textbox on the control.

Comment: Calling the method from a telerik tab click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just have the property wrap the control?  This way, the control manages viewstate for you:

```
public string SubjectTextBoxText
{
     get { return TextBox1.Text; }
     set { Textbox1.Text = value; }
}
```

This is the approach I've taken and it works great.

Comment: Alright it's working. Problem solved. How do I split acceptance between you and Matthew?