# Unable to step into debug mode into WPF control from Windows Form

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, wpf-controls, elementhost

I am using [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) Control to embed a custom WPF control that I have created into a windows from application. Earlier I was able to debug the WPF control by pressing the F11 button when the control was created:

```
MyControl.UserControl1 obj = new MyControl.UserControl1(_Action, true);
elementHost1.Child = obj;
elementHost1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

But now I am trying to debug the same code after migrating from XP to Windows 8 machine and I am not able to enter into the debug mode for WPF control. Can any one please help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873225/visual-studio-2010-step-into-property-functionf11-doesnt-work-as-expected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On debug, right click on the line and uncheck "Step over properties and operators"
[image: Step over property]