# c# break dataset exception in my code visual studio

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012

When i sometimes screw up with my datasets i got a problem, Visual studio does not show me where in my code i forgot to check for null value before using it or whatever, it breaks in the generated dataset code

```
 public string Avdeling {
            get {
                try {
                    return ((string)(this[this.tableLMG_hoved.AvdelingColumn]));
                }
                catch (global::System.InvalidCastException e) {
                    throw new global::System.Data.StrongTypingException("The value for column \'Avdeling\' in table \'LMG_hoved\' is DBNull.", e);
                }
            }
            set {
                this[this.tableLMG_hoved.AvdelingColumn] = value;
            }
        }
```

When i want it to break in this line

```
a.Avdeling = rad.Avdeling;
```

I managed once before to set up Visual studio to break in my code instead of the dataset, but when i innstalled VS 2013 this setting i think was reset or something. I cannot find back to the old ways and now i use so much time in figuring out the source of the dataset exception.

Anybody now how i should set ut VS debug settings?

Comment: I'm not sure where the option is in VS2012 exactly, as I mostly use VS2010 myself, but I the answer to this question should make the debugger stop inside the getter:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873225/visual-studio-2010-step-into-property-functionf11-doesnt-work-as-expected

Answer (score 0):

I can't find that option at the moment, but when it breaks open the call stack window (Debug-->Windows-->Call Stack) you can double click on the second line to find what called that property (the first line is the current place in the program).