# 'Step Into' not working in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net

When I put breakpoint inside a line and I click on 'start debugging' and after running the page when I press F11,My step into (F11)  is not working!!!?
I am using VS 2010 and debugging C# class library in Debug Mode.
what do I do?Please help me!
I tried ([Step Into Property/Function (F11) doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873225/step-into-property-function-f11-doesnt-work-as-expected)) But it didn't help me!!

Comment: We can't possibly know.  Can you provide more information about specifically what you're doing?  Maybe show some screen shots and indicate exactly what steps you take?

Comment: I guess the poster can't upload images with that reputation. @sara: put images on some external host if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Here is [an answer to a similar question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/95e759a5-5515-44fc-96e5-d51330fd06c1/how-to-fix-debugger-f11-does-not-work):

```
Please go to Tools->Options...->Debugging->General, and uncheck "Enable Just My Code (Managed only)" option and check "Suppress JIT optimization on module load (managed only)".

If you want to debug into the .NET Framework source code, please:
 1. Turn OFF the "Enable Just My Code" option
 2. Turn ON the "Enable Source Server Support" option.
For the deailed steps to configure Visual Studio to debug into the Framework source code, please refer to this article.
```