# Debugger converts step into private method to step over

Tags: c#, debugging, asp.net-web-api

I have a class called MyClient. MyClient has a method called GetStuff that looks like this:

```
public List<Stuff> GetStuff(string query) 
{
    var result = Send<Stuff>("/stuff", query)
    return Parse<Stuff>(result);  
}
```

When I try to debug and step into Send and/or Parse I get a message my step into action has been converted into step over. Much like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672996/your-step-into-request-resulted-in-an-automatic-step-over-of-a-property-or-opera) question.

However, `Send` and `Parse` are not properties. They are private methods in the same class that I can successfully debug. I have disabled the setting to skip properties in Tools -> Debugging -> General and it still skips it. In fact, even if I do not try to step into Send, and only go on to my next breakpoint at the Parse line it immediately steps out of GetStuff. I can not view the intermediate result.

One thing that I think is key is that MyClient references System.Web.Http 5.2.3.0 and uses it to make requests. I use the project containing MyClient as a git submodule in a solution that uses System.Web.Http 4.0.0.0. I solved this conflict by creating an explicit reference to where to find 5.2.3.0 in my Web.config as shown in burtons answer. I did this because upgrading properly would start a chain of death that would take very long to fix. I will do this later, but right now it is not an option.

I am using VS2015.

Any help would be extremely appreciated as I am completely stuck and can not debug my own code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I had the exact same problem. The suggested solution didn't help at first, but for some reason when I tried it again a few days later, it solved the problem. I think it's a bug, one of not a few in VS 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found the cause. I was getting a `FileLoadException` when trying to load System.Web.Http. This occured when calling `Send` but not within the method itself. Further my settings for when to halt on an exception were not correct so it looked like the debugger just skipped the method.