# Visual Studio 2019 step over properties and operators not working?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

Anyone else finding that the Debugging/General "Step over properties and operators (Managed only)" setting is not working properly in Visual Studio Enterprise 2019?

I have it checked yet I am still stepping into properties when pressing F11 to step into a method.

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix it or a work around?

Comment: What did you mean that the option is not working? Did you see a message window which shows `our step-into request resulted in an automatic step-over of a property or operator.`? That message is not an error message as such. And it tells us that it will step over some code as the option did. If your situation is this, just click `no` and you will never get the message next time.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT What I meant by not working is that with that option checked, I still stepped into the property.  However, it is fixed now. I'll post an answer below explaining what I did.

Answer (score 8):

My question wasn't concerning the notification.  My question was regarding the fact that even though I had the option checked to "Step over properties and operators", pressing F11 to step into a method still stepped into the properties.

This is now working for me as it is supposed to though.  I'm not exactly sure what fixed it but I will explain what I did so that if someone else experiences this problem, maybe some of what resolved it for me will resolve it for them.

I unchecked the checkbox and clicked OK, and then opened the Options back up re-checked the checkbox and clicked OK.  Also, I think the debugger was actually running when I did it (this time).  I am also 99.9% sure that I have done this in the past, perhaps without the debugger running or clicking OK between unchecking and re-checking, but it didn't fix the problem in the past.  Perhaps unchecking, clicking OK, opening the Options, checking the checkbox, and clicking OK resolved it?  Or maybe doing this while the debugger was running fixed it?

Comment: Since you have a workaround,  I suggest you could mark your own answer:)

Comment: You can [mark your answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) since it is a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

If you face the message window like this after you enable the option **Step over properties and operators (Managed only)** and press **F11** to step into a property:

[image]

This is just a prompt message telling us that vs will skip the trace of some certain code, such as **Properties**, If you select no, this message will never appear again, and **F11** will skip properties and operators as expected. Also, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672996/your-step-into-request-resulted-in-an-automatic-step-over-of-a-property-or-opera) reminder this.

[image]

[image]

===============================================================

**Besides**, if you get this and still can step into the properties or operators, please try these steps to troubleshoot the issue:

**1)** disable any installed third party vs extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions**

**2)** reset all settings under **Tools**-->**Import and Export Settings**-->**Reset vs settings**

**3)** close VS Instance, enter your project path, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder.

**4)** [repair vs on the vs installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update it to the latest vs if there is any update.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue and actually there is a very easy solution to this.

1. Export all your settings
2. Reset all settings
3. Import all your settings back except Options->Debugging

[Import and Export Settings Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flU2J.png)