# Visual Studio debugger loops through C# property getters for XAML ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, debugging

I am trying to debug my WPF, but every time I start debugging the debugger loops through my object properties for a list (ListView in XAML) despite stepping over. Is there any way to prevent this?:
[image]

[image]

[image]

XAML:

```
<ListView
    Name="lstMovies"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="1"
    FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Movies}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentMovie, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectionChanged="lstMovies_SelectionChanged"
    SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <!--  COLUMN WIDTHS FITTED WITH AUTO AND MEASURED WITH PowerToys  -->
                <GridViewColumn
                    Width="235"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Title}"
                    Header="Title" />
                <GridViewColumn
                    Width="65"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Genre}"
                    Header="Genre" />
                <GridViewColumn
                    Width="76"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=RunningTime}"
                    Header="Running Time" />
                <GridViewColumn
                    Width="109"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Instructor}"
                    Header="Instructor" />
                <GridViewColumn
                    Width="93"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PremiereDate}"
                    Header="  Premiere Date  " />
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672996/your-step-into-request-resulted-in-an-automatic-step-over-of-a-property-or-opera

Comment: @RandRandom Tried unchecking the option and running it again - the debugger still seems to loop through each property for all objects in the ListView. I have a suspicion it's caused by the XAML or something else as it happens after the codeblock finishing